# Python randomly select an element from a 2D array and add to it

Tags: python, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

how can I randomly select an element from a 2d array and then add to it?

```
amount_to_add = 13
my_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
```

I want to randomly add 13 to one of the elements so it'd look like

```
my_array = [[0,0],[0,13],[0,0],[0,0]]
```

Comment: Is the output `my_array` supposed to have an additional list in it? Or should it be the same length as the original `my_array`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)
```

Just that simple.

Demo:

```
>>> my_array = [[0],[0],[0],[0]]
>>> my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)
>>> my_array[random.randrange(len(my_array))].append(amount_to_add)
>>> my_array
[[0], [0], [0, 10], [0, 10]]
```

Edit: Turns out i misunderstood the question. Here is how to add:

```
>>> my_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> random.choice(my_array)[random.randrange(len(choice))] += amount_to_add
>>> my_array
[[0, 10], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> random.choice(my_array)[random.randrange(len(choice))] += amount_to_add
>>> my_array
[[0, 10], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 10]]
```

Comment: This adds a new element to a random sublist.  Not what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> from random import choice, randint
>>> amount_to_add = 13
>>> my_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> element = choice(my_array)
>>> element[randint(0, len(element)-1)] += amount_to_add
>>> my_array
[[13, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> my_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> element = choice(my_array)
>>> [randint(0, len(element)-1)] += amount_to_add
>>> my_array
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 13]]
>>>
```

It randomly chooses an element in `my_array`, randomly chooses an index on that element, and then adds `amount_to_add` to the item at that index.